# Can I retrieve YouTube videos from C#/.NET?

Tags: c#, .net, youtube, youtube-api

I'd like to do a querystring to the YouTube API and get (server side, with C#/.NET) the response, storing the information on my application.

I know how to do it with javascript, but can I do this directly from the server side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure you can. Refer to [documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_dotnet.html) for details.